# Obtener objeto con Linq con sus referencias

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo esta consulta en LinQ, llené el objeto con la consulta pero no completa una variable de objeto.

El modelo de `Retención` tiene una variable `Empresa` que es otro modelo, y es el que no llena, permanece nulo:

```
public class Retencion
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Año { get; set; }
    public string Nit { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public int Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Cuenta { get; set; }
    public string Concepto { get; set; }
    public int Base { get; set; }
    public int Porcentaje { get; set; }
    public int Valor { get; set; }

    public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
}

public List<Retencion> Get(string nit, string ano)
{
    List<Retencion> result = new List<Retencion>();
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(ano);

    try
    {
        result = (from p in _context.Retencion
                  join e in _context.Empresa on p.EmpresaId equals e.ID
                  where (p.Año == a && p.Nit == nit)
                  select p).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento de generar la consulta con Linq te hace falta una conversión de un tipo anómino (genérado por Linq) al tipo que desees, dicho de otra manera, la consulta de Linq obtiene un tipo anónimo y lo que tu requieres es un tipo `List<Retencion>`. Se requiere modificar a lo siguiente:

```
result = (from p in _context.Retencion
            join e in _context.Empresa on p.EmpresaId equals e.ID
            where (p.Año == a && p.Nit == nit)
            select new Retencion
            {
                ID = p.ID,
                Año = p.Año,
                Nit = p.Nit,
                Nombre = p.Nombre,
                Direccion = p.Direccion,
                Telefono = p.Telefono,
                Tipo = p.Tipo,
                Cuenta = p.Cuenta,
                Concepto = p.Concept,
                Base = p.Base,
                Porcentaje = p.Porcentaje,
                Valor = p.Valor,
                Empresa = e,
                EmpresaId = e.EmpresaId
            }).ToList();
```

En caso de que estés usando Entity Framework, la tarea se simplifica ya que puedes incluir las referencias de cada entidad, por ejemplo, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
result = (from p in _context.Retencion
          join e in _context.Empresa on p.EmpresaId equals e.ID
          where (p.Año == a && p.Nit == nit)
          select p).Include("Empresa").ToList();
```

Para esto, debes asegurarte de tener la referencia al *namespace* `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Comment: Gracias, eso era lo que me faltaba. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

```
     result = (from p in _context.Retencion
              join e in _context.Empresa on p.EmpresaId equals e.ID
              _context.Retencion.Include("Empresa")
              where (p.Año == a && p.Nit == nit)
              select p).ToList();
```

Te dejo [***este link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315966/how-do-you-construct-a-linq-to-entities-query-to-load-child-objects-directly-in) con una pregunta similar en ingles